# how to get 'c#.net' from url but getting only c'' from querystring in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

`http://localhost:4858/Search.aspx?search=C#.NET`

```
string CourseName = Request.QueryString["search"].ToString();
```

In Above code the Querystring retrieving only `C` but i want to get complete `C#.NET` value from url how to achieve this any solution.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to encode `#` to `%23`. Otherwise it's being treated as a fragment identifier and will not be sent to the server.

Comment: @haim770 : any example code how to encode url

Comment: Code behave correctly so not clear why you aren't happy with results. Whoever constructed url probably did it wrong (or query is really "c" and you just expect hash to be part of the query when it is not) - ask them to search for proper ways to add query parameter to url.

Answer (score 2):

The `#` in a URL marks the fragment, which is not sent to the server.

You need to URL-encode your query.

Comment: That depends on how you're building the URL.  Google it.

Comment: by using JSON i'm building URL